# Asterisk 13 - Call Transfer Agent to Agent Macro

Tags: asterisk

I'm using asterisk 13, and testing call transfer by 'transfer' agent to agent. Agent 191 in call.

```
Agent-ID  Name                 State       Channel                        Talking with
191       atendente.virtual9   INUSE       SIP/6039-00000019              Local/003230514418@from-internal-00000034;1
```

the call will be transferred to Agent 109.

```
same => n,Transfer(Local/109);
```

Transfer Status Return is

```
-- Executing [s@macro-transfer:6] NoOp("Local/003230514418@from-internal-0000002d;1", "UNSUPPORTED") in new stack
```

Is the form being used using the transfer correct?

in version 12 I was using 'AgentRequest'

```
exten => _ZX.,1,NoOp(AGENTE ${EXTEN});
same => n,Set(TIMEINI=${EPOCH});
same => n,AgentRequest(${EXTEN});
same => n,NoOp(AGENT_STATUS is ${AGENT_STATUS});
same => n,Hangup();
```

But the version 13 agent that transferred was kept busy and prevented from receiving a new connection until the transfer ended, so I am trying to use the 'transfer' command.

Answer (score 1):

You have channel of type sip(most likly).
But you are transfering to

same => n,Transfer(Local/109);

Channel of type local. Transfer of sip to DIFFERNT channel type is not posible for technical reason. Local channel not support transfer at all as far as i know.

Comment: do you have any example of transfer between agents?